# Creating custom color inside PWA flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, colors, progressive-web-apps

Hi I am trying to build an PWA from my existing project of flutter apps... Inside of my flutter apps, I am using custom color that I define in a file.. here is it

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

const first= Color(0xxxxxxxxxxxx);
const second= Color(0xxxxxxxxx);
const third= Color(0xxxxxxxx);
const vio= LinearGradient( // I get red line here
  colors: <Color>[first, second, third], // from this line I get red line with note: The named parameter 'colors' isn't defined.
  stops: [0.2, 0.5, 1.3],// same goes for this line
  begin: Alignment.centerLeft,
  end: Alignment.centerRight,
);
```

I am doing trial by adding that file into my PWA project, but the `colors` and `stops` always can not be defined... from this case, is there something that I should add inside the `web` folder of my PWA project?

Comment: what is `ColorGradient` class? what package did you use?

Comment: @pskink sorry I am doing mistake... I have edited the code above

Comment: if you go the the definition of `LinearGradient`, what do you see? something like this: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/c969b8af7b/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/gradient.dart#L357?

Comment: from the link you have given, the code from line of 336-346 is the thing that I wanna try, but I didn't able to do it in pwa project, I can only use it inside flutter apps project... am I doing wrong or should I add something?

Comment: what file do you see if you go to the definition of your `LinearGradient`? just press control key and click on `LinearGradient`, is it `painting/gradient.dart` or some other file?

Comment: I just found out what you mean, thank you very much for your help

Comment: so what was it?

Comment: defining class of LinearGradient

Comment: post a self answer then, it could be helpful to others

Comment: I will post it when I already know the correct one, now I will try it first